# Resources directory not found on classpath

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij 13, and I've marked a directory as a resources directory (thinking that this would make all sub-files/folders available on the classpath), however when I run the project, an exception is thrown saying that a file called database.properties (inside the resources folder) can't be found at runtime.

[image]

Any ideas?

'database' folder is the folder marked as a resources folder.

Comment: Why not just move `database.properties` inside `resources`? It will make things a lot easier when you build the project with Maven

Comment: I could do that, I just want to know why it isn't working at the moment

Comment: You simple missing the default directory layout and the conventions. You should put your property files into src/main/resrouces and **not** into src/main/java. Thats the reason why it's not working.

Comment: It's not in src/main/java, is in src/main

Answer (score 1):

I do not know intellij-idea, but I know that maven can deal with multiple resources directory provided they are declared in `pom.xml`. From Maven doc on [Mave Resources plugin - Specifying resources directories](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html) :

```
...
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>resource1</directory>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>resource2</directory>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>resource3</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
...
```

If IntelliJ-IDEA has not declared your `database` directory such way in the pom, maven has no chance to find it.